# Is there a file server proxy which provides lesser disk space keeping and providing commonly used files on itself

Tags: file, caching, server, proxy

Most software is used by many users. People migrates to cloud and they use virtual machines and big file servers in production environments. I configured some of them. The idea struck me if there would be a very fast nvme array holding common files of microsoft office and some design software it would be very efficient for disk space usage. Caching doesn't seem to work efficiently with qcow2 and vmdk files over nbd netowork file systems.

Bottom line is there a setup like this to prevent clutter of same files on different disk. It would preserve a lot disk space.